# Creating map with predefined keys in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to create a map with predefined key just like a class?

In Python, it can be achieved like this:

```
class SomeClass(dict):
    def __init__(self, valtype=int):
        self['a'] = 1
        self['b'] = 2
        self['c'] = 3
```

The reason I want to do this is because I want to use different variable depend on the condition.
For example:

```
int someFunction(someClass c, std::string variableName)
{
    if (c[variableName] < 10)
    {
        ...
    }
    ....
}
```

Thank you ~

Answer (score 1):

You can use an *initializer_list* to provide the [key, value] pairs of a `std::map` at the point of its declaration.

- Initializer list for a `std::map` is a comma-separated list of key/value pairs
- Initializer list is enclosed in braces `{}`
- Each key/value pair is enclosed in braces
- Comma (,) separates key and value

Here is an example.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::map< std::string, int > roman_numerals
    {
        // This is the initializer list.
        { "I", 1 }, { "II", 2 }, { "III", 3 }, { "IV", 4 }, { "V", 5 }
    };
    for (auto const& [roman, value] : roman_numerals)
    {
        std::cout
            << "Roman numeral: " << std::setw(5) << roman
            << ", value: " << value << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
Roman numeral:     I, value: 1
Roman numeral:    II, value: 2
Roman numeral:   III, value: 3
Roman numeral:    IV, value: 4
Roman numeral:     V, value: 5
```

Comment: I see!! Thank you ~

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

class SomeClass {
 public:
  int operator[](const std::string& key) const { return map_.at(key); }

 private:
  static inline const std::map<std::string, int> map_{{"a", 1},
                                                      {"b", 2},
                                                      {"c", 3}};
};

void someFunction(SomeClass c, std::string variableName) {
  if (c[variableName] < 10) {
  }
}

int main() {
  someFunction(SomeClass{}, "b");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And if I want to change the values, I could do the same thing by overloading the '=' operator right?

Comment: Right, there no limitations.